# How can I get the nested components of a <p:column> in a facelet using EL

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces, dynamic-columns

Let's say I have this:

```xhtml
<p:column headerText="R"
          style=" text-align: center;"
          width="10"
          rendered="true">
  <p:commandLink id="MRepShowButton" update=":form1:display" onclick="EditorDialog.show();"  title="Editer le compte rendu"> 
  <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{exam}" target="#{dyna.selectedExamen}" />  
     <p:graphicImage id="img1" value="/images/study_Report_icons/Text/0.png" rendered="#{exam.examen.rapport.rapportWrittenState == null}"/>
     <p:graphicImage id="img2" value="/images/study_Report_icons/Text/#{exam.examen.rapport.rapportWrittenState}.png" rendered="#{exam.examen.rapport.rapportWrittenState != null}"/>
  </p:commandLink>
</p:column>
```

Now how can I achieve that using the `<p:columns>`

```xhtml
<p:columns value="#{tableBean.columns}" var="column" columnIndexVar="colIndex" 
           sortBy="#{column.property}" filterBy="#{column.property}">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        #{column.header}
                    </f:facet>

                    #{car[column.property]}

                </p:columns>
```

all the examples and tutorials about this topic only covers the simple `<h:outptText>` what about components (p:graphicImage,p:commandLink ,etc..) nested in a column like the code above.
 how do you achieve that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can render any element inside the <p:columns> element.

What you want to do is probably render the cell contents differently, depending on the column. You can try something like this :

```
  //classic rendering (for all cells)
  <h:outputText value="#{car[column.property]}"/>

  //conditional rendering (for 'report' cells only)
  <h:panelGroup rendered="#{column.property == 'report'}">
    <p:commandLink id="MRepShowButton" update=":form1:display" onclick="EditorDialog.show();"  title="Editer le compte rendu">
      <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{exam}" target="#{dyna.selectedExamen}" />  
      <p:graphicImage id="img1" value="/images/study_Report_icons/Text/0.png" rendered="#{exam.examen.rapport.rapportWrittenState == null}"/>
      <p:graphicImage id="img2" value="/images/study_Report_icons/Text/#{exam.examen.rapport.rapportWrittenState}.png" rendered="#{exam.examen.rapport.rapportWrittenState != null}"/>
    </p:commandLink>
  </h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: it gives error on not founding properties, i think the problem is with the property of properties : prop1.prop2.prop3, the error is javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException

Comment: Is the error on "exam.examen.rapport.rapportWrittenState" ? exam is you datatable var (that represent one row object), then check you getExamen() method, then check the getRapport() method of your Examen object, then check getRapportWrittenState method of your Rapport object... Also, I suppose dyna is your backing bean ?

Comment: If exam type is Examen class, you don't need to write `exam.examen.rapport.rapportWrittenState}.png` but `exam.rapport.rapportWrittenState}.png`

Comment: Look if i used p:datatable with binding everything works just fine, only i need to click twice to update the p:datatable of which i couldn't understand why or even resolve, so i thought about using p:columns as an alternative solution, my real problem is how can i achieve the whole thing with p:columns, i give to the p:columns value an ArrayList of p:column created exactly as i want to with the order that i want, but showing them is the hard part.

Comment: to answer correctly your first comment the error is given on the first column to show, the facelet doesn't understand the EL when it evaluates to property of property e.g :dyna.selectedExamen.examen.rapport.rapportId

Comment: I guess what's wrong. You can't use nested properties for the columnModel.property. #{car['something']} is a short for  #car.something, ie "car.getSomething()" on bean side. That is invalid if property name contains dots. I don't see another syntax that would do, but you can create direct properties on your exam class. Example : `public String getRapportID() { return getExamen().getRapport().getID(); }` and so use rapportID as property name.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44017/discussion-between-papa-jay-and-stephane-lallemagne)